# semver Release Candidate regex validation

Tags: regex, semantic-versioning

I haven't coded in a while and I have to validate a semantic version of an artifact and validate it's a release candidate ending with ie ending with "-rc?" using regex.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you mean `/-rc$/`? Can you elaborate exactly what input and output you are dealing with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm fairly bad at regex... I have to read a pom file and extract the version. from that version, I want to check if its a SNAPSHOT or RC version (1.2.22-SNAPSHOT or 1.2.22-rc1). the rc can be rc1 and can be incremented

Comment: this is what I have so far : taken from an example : https://www.regextester.com/103662

Comment: OK, that helps. Can you post all of these examples and your attempt into the question itself? The problem is, I can't tell what your requirements are. Which of these are _supposed_ to be matched and why? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I need to have a regex that will confirm that my version ends with -rc1 -rc2 etc.. and only this.

Comment: OK, then see my top post in this comment thread. Does this solve the problem? If you have a digit or more at the end, add `/-rc\d+$/`. The `$` anchor is end of line.